# pandas dataframe - two column string match and group

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which contains strings in two columns.
I want to for each of the columns extract all strings which are similar except the numerical digits and add new columns where the similar text is exchanged against a idx value.

From this:

```
Id    Name1    Name2
0     Alpha 1  Bravo 3
1     Alpha 2  Alpha 2
2     Bravo 3  Alpha 1
```

To This:

```
Id    Name1    Name2    NewCol1    NewCol2
0     Alpha 1  Bravo 3  1          2
1     Alpha 2  Zero  2  1          3
2     Bravo 3  Alpha 1  2          1
```

Is there a simple solution to this without a big iteration loop?

Answer (score 3):

I think need create `Series` with `MultiIndex` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), remove `digit`s and for categories use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html), last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
s = df.set_index('Id').stack().str.replace('\d+', '')

df = df.join(pd.Series(pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1, index=s.index).unstack().add_prefix('New'))
print (df)
   Id    Name1    Name2  NewName1  NewName2
0   0  Alpha 1  Bravo 3         1         2
1   1  Alpha 2   Zero 2         1         3
2   2  Bravo 3  Alpha 1         2         1
```

**Details**:

```
print (s)
Id       
0   Name1    Alpha 
    Name2    Bravo 
1   Name1    Alpha 
    Name2     Zero 
2   Name1    Bravo 
    Name2    Alpha 
dtype: object

print (pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1)
[1 2 1 3 2 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a loop to iterate over column names. For rows use `pandas.Series.str.replace`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1' :['Alpha 1', 'Aplha 2', 'Bravo 3'], 'Name2' : ['Bravo 3', 'Alpha 2', 'Alpha 1']})
for name in df.columns.tolist():
    df["newCol" + name.replace("Name", "")] = df[name].str.split(expand=True)[1]
```

Comment: This was not exactly what i meant.. this sequence only extract the last digit. The digit is not important.. it's the text that should match without the digit.